# How can I use bottom navigation and navigation drawers together? v-app doesn't work

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am new to vuetify and vue, I want to create a layout in which the users with **sm** or smaller screens will use the bottom-navigation component and the users with **md** or higher will use the navigation drawers.

I am using the v-app component, that according to the docs "help bootstrap your application with the proper sizing around  component" and "These (components) can be mixed and matched and only one of each particular component should exist at any time."

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-navigation-drawer app>
      <v-list rounded>
        <v-subheader>REPORTS</v-subheader>
        <v-list-item-group v-model="item" color="primary">
          <v-list-item v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="i">
            <v-list-item-icon>
              <v-icon v-text="item.icon"></v-icon>
            </v-list-item-icon>
            <v-list-item-content>
              <v-list-item-title v-text="item.text"></v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item-content>
          </v-list-item>
        </v-list-item-group>
      </v-list>
    </v-navigation-drawer>

    <v-app-bar app>
      <v-toolbar-title class="headline text-uppercase">
        <span>Vuetify</span>
        <span class="font-weight-light">MATERIAL DESIGN</span>
      </v-toolbar-title>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-btn text href="https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/releases/latest" target="_blank">
        <span class="mr-2">Latest Release</span>
      </v-btn>
    </v-app-bar>

    <v-content fluid>
      <HelloWorld />
    </v-content>

    <v-bottom-navigation app>
      <v-btn value="recent">
        <span>Recent</span>
        <v-icon>history</v-icon>
      </v-btn>

      <v-btn value="favorites">
        <span>Favorites</span>
        <v-icon>favorite</v-icon>
      </v-btn>

      <v-btn value="nearby">
        <span>Nearby</span>
        <v-icon>place</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
    </v-bottom-navigation>

  </v-app>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from "vue";
import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld.vue";

export default Vue.extend({
  name: "App",
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  },
  data: () => ({
    item: 1,
    items: [
      { text: "Real-Time", icon: "mdi-clock" },
      { text: "Audience", icon: "mdi-account" },
      { text: "Conversions", icon: "mdi-flag" }
    ]
  })
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

So the documentation it's perhaps a bit unclear from the text.

It's up to you to display them as you see fit. But you should for example not have two v-app-bars visible at the same time.

So here is the solution:

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-navigation-drawer app v-model="$vuetify.breakpoint.mdAndUp" stateless class="hidden-sm-and-down">
      <v-list rounded>
        <v-subheader>REPORTS</v-subheader>
        <v-list-item-group v-model="item" color="primary">
          <v-list-item v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="i">
            <v-list-item-icon>
              <v-icon v-text="item.icon"></v-icon>
            </v-list-item-icon>
            <v-list-item-content>
              <v-list-item-title v-text="item.text"></v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item-content>
          </v-list-item>
        </v-list-item-group>
      </v-list>
    </v-navigation-drawer>

    <v-app-bar app class="hidden-sm-and-down">
      <v-toolbar-title class="headline text-uppercase">
        <span>Vuetify</span>
        <span class="font-weight-light">MATERIAL DESIGN</span>
      </v-toolbar-title>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-btn text href="https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/releases/latest" target="_blank">
        <span class="mr-2">Latest Release</span>
      </v-btn>
    </v-app-bar>

    <v-content fluid>
      <HelloWorld />
    </v-content>

    <v-bottom-navigation app class="d-flex d-md-none">
      <v-btn value="recent">
        <span>Recent</span>
        <v-icon>history</v-icon>
      </v-btn>

      <v-btn value="favorites">
        <span>Favorites</span>
        <v-icon>favorite</v-icon>
      </v-btn>

      <v-btn value="nearby">
        <span>Nearby</span>
        <v-icon>place</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
    </v-bottom-navigation>

  </v-app>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from "vue";
import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld.vue";

export default Vue.extend({
  name: "App",
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  },
  data: () => ({
    item: 1,
    items: [
      { text: "Real-Time", icon: "mdi-clock" },
      { text: "Audience", icon: "mdi-account" },
      { text: "Conversions", icon: "mdi-flag" }
    ]
  })
});
</script>
```